# What is the limit of hibernate in clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

we know hibernate has this in clause:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in(userIds));
```

Is there any limit on the size of userIds (which is an ArrayList, say)?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK: the limit is the memory the host computer can hold **OR** `Integer.MAX_LIMIT` in the case you have _unlimited memory_

Comment: HIbernate might not have a limit, but the database in question might.

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on the particular database you use. For example [in Oracle this limit is 1000](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions014.htm).
If you need to pass more values you need to use another approach. For example put the values into a temporary table and then do a `select where id in (select id from temptable)` query.